# Using Bazel platform select with load

Tags: bazel

I have a bazel file that has to load two different requirements files:

```
load("@python_turing_libs//:requirements.bzl", "requirement")
```

or

```
load("@python_ampere_libs//:requirements.bzl", "requirement")
```

I was hoping to use bazel platforms to do this via:

```
# Define GPU constraint values
constraint_setting(name = "gpu")
constraint_value(name = "turing", constraint_setting = "gpu")
constraint_value(name = "ampere", constraint_setting = "gpu")
constraint_value(name = "none", constraint_setting = "gpu")

# Platform
platform(
    name = "gpu_server",
    constraint_values = [
        "@platforms//os:linux",
        "@platforms//cpu:x86_64",
        ":gpu",
    ],
)

select({
        "@platforms//os:linux": 
            load("@python_perception_libs//:requirements.bzl", "requirement")
        ,
        "//conditions:default": [],
    })
```

```
syntax error at 'load': expected expression
```

or something, but clearly this syntax does not work

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a mechanism to conditionally load from other bzl files, so instead, load both files, and use selects to select the different things within those files.

One issue is that the symbols have the same name in each file, and to address that you can have different symbols in the file that's doing the loading like this:

```
load("@python_turing_libs//:requirements.bzl", turing_requirement = "requirement")
load("@python_ampere_libs//:requirements.bzl", ampere_requirement = "requirement")


your_rule(
  ...
  some_attribute = select({
    ":turing_condition": turing_requirement,
    ":ampere_condition": ampere_requirement,
  })
  ...
)
```

Comment: Can you show me a full working example. I can't seem to figure out the syntax exactly

Comment: how do i actually pass to the command line that i want turing_condition?

Comment: A full working example depends a lot on what you're trying to accomplish, and what libraries and frameworks and languages you're trying to get working together. Platforms are a pretty advanced part of Bazel, and most of the time only rule writers have to use them a lot. It might be better to start a discussion on bazel-discuss@googlegroups.com starting from the beginning from what you want to accomplish.